# Make Meteor Schemas accessible sitewide using global variables

Tags: javascript, meteor, global-variables

I am trying to get to grips with using SimpleSchemas in my Meteor app.

I have had no problem defining them all and I can see the validation rules working but I've just added the autoForm package and when I try to use the schemas I've already defined I can't seem to access the object they're stored in. I'm assuming this is an issue with my lack of understanding around what makes a variable global etc.

In a file called `schemas.js` inside my `/collections` directory I have

```
var Schemas = {};

Schemas.AddressDetails = new SimpleSchema({
  address_line_1: {
    type: String,
  }
  ...
});

Schemas.ContactDetails = new SimpleSchema({
  address: {
    type: Schemas.AddressDetails
  }
});

...
```

But if I then try and access this `Schemas` object from within a file located within the `/client/pages/<page>.js` using the following code I get an error when autoForm tries to access the schema as it can't be found.

```
Template.admOrganisationSetupStepOne.helpers({
  schema: function() {
    return Schemas.ContactDetails;
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to check if the schema is defined before returning it in the helper. Or put your schema file inside a /lib folder, then you are sure that the schema gets loaded before your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears I had done two things wrong.

My Schemas.js file needed to be ran from with `/lib` directory so that it would be executed before any of my other code could be loaded. Thanks [Bjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934216/bj%c3%b8rn-br%c3%a5then)

My second mistake was that I had defined `Schemas = {};` with the `var` prefix. By calling `var` it limited the use of the Schemas object meaning it couldn't be used within a different page or script.

Comment: I don't know where that "var" gotcha is documented but I just spent HOURS trying to figure out what was going wrong. Thank you for your answer!